# Title over 150 chars, about JTextField and JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtextfield

Would be title: Why does the JTextField go away when I uncomment line 40, how would I add the Ellipse2D.double ball to the JPanel, and is there a better thing to use than JPanel.

I'm trying to make a basic game where you use the WASD keys to move a ball. The input is in the JTextField, which goes away when I add the JPanel. After that, how would I go about adding ball to the JPanel. Also, is JPanel used for a place to draw images?

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.*;
@SuppressWarnings({ "serial" })
public class WASD extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
  Ellipse2D.Double ball = new Ellipse2D.Double(10,10,10,10);
    int ballx = 100;
    int bally = 100;
    JTextField typingArea;
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        WASD frame = new WASD("frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.addComponentsToPane();

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private void addComponentsToPane(){
        typingArea = new JTextField(20);
        add(typingArea);
        typingArea.addKeyListener(this);
        JPanel drawingArea = new JPanel();
        add(drawingArea); // Line 40
    }
    public WASD(String name){
        super(name);
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Goodbye.");
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Are you still there?");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does the JTextField go away when I uncomment line 40

Because `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` as its default layout manager.  By adding the panel you are effectively removing the text field and replacing it with the panel

Check out

- [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
- [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

for more details...

> Also, is JPanel used for a place to draw images?

Yes `JPanel` is (probably) the best place to start with custom painting.

Check out...

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

for more details

> I'm trying to make a basic game where you use the WASD keys to move a
>   ball

`JTextField` is not the best choice for controlling this, see [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: Thanks so much!

Note to people from the future who may see this: you also need to do drawingArea.setFocusable(true).

Comment: Only if you insist on using `KeyListener`, Key bindings are unaffected by this draw back (that's why we recommend using them)